# Error with values in structs

Tags: struct, racket, let

I have started to build a small game in racket using the `2htdp/universe` library. My code so far:

```
#lang racket
(require 2htdp/image 2htdp/universe)

(define BIRD-IMG (scale .2 (object:image% ...)) ; Image URL: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vz26B.png

(struct world (bird) #:transparent)
(struct pos (x y) #:transparent)
(struct bird (pos img) #:transparent)

(define-values (WIDTH HEIGHT)
  (values 600 600))

(define DEFAULT-STATE (world (bird (pos (/ WIDTH 2) (/ HEIGHT 2)) BIRD-IMG)))

(define (move-bird w x y dir)
  (world
   (bird
    (pos
     (let
         ([new-x (+ (pos-x (bird-pos (world-bird w))) x)]
          [new-y (+ (pos-y (bird-pos (world-bird w))) y)])
       (values
        (cond
          [(> new-x WIDTH) WIDTH]
          [(< new-x 0) 0]
          [else new-x])
        (cond
          [(> new-y HEIGHT) HEIGHT]
          [(< new-y 0) 0]
          [else new-y]))))
    (case dir
      [("up") BIRD-IMG]
      [("down") (rotate 180 BIRD-IMG)]
      [("left") (rotate 90 BIRD-IMG)]
      [("right") (rotate -90 BIRD-IMG)]
      [else (bird-img (world-bird w))]))))

(define (render w)
  (place-image (bird-img (world-bird w))
               (pos-x (bird-pos (world-bird w)))
               (pos-y (bird-pos (world-bird w)))
               (empty-scene WIDTH HEIGHT)))

(define (handle-keys w key)
  (case key
    [("up") (move-bird w 0 -5 key)]
    [("down") (move-bird w 0 5 key)]
    [("left") (move-bird w -5 0 key)]
    [("right") (move-bird w 5 0 key)]
    [else w]))

(big-bang DEFAULT-STATE
          (on-draw render)
          (on-key handle-keys)
          (on-tick (lambda (w) w) 20)
          (name "Bird Simulator 2016"))
```

My problem: When I try to press the arrow keys to move the bird in a direction, there is an error in the 'move-bird' function:

```
result arity mismatch;
 expected number of values not received
  expected: 1
  received: 2
  values...:
```

Running it through DrRacket's debugger, I can see that it is where the variables from the let have gone out of scope, but the program is at a lower level than the outermost `world` struct. I am confused because the arity mismatch error didn't name any particular place/function, and I certainly don't see any place where more values are given then are required. The `world` struct is passed only a `bird` struct, and the `bird` struct only a `pos` and an `img`. It might have to do with the `let` inside of the `pos` struct, but I am not sure. Please help!

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguous title, I couldn't think of anything better. Feel free to edit it.

Comment: You are returning two values from the `let`, but the `pos` constructor expects two separate arguments, not a single argument of two values (there is a difference). Remove the wrapping `pos` and replace the `values` with `pos` and that should fix your problem.